# Append pandas.core.categorical.Categories

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to subset every nth category, and then append the last category.

Here is an example:

1) Making the categories

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
b = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
c = pd.cut(x = b.tolist(), bins = a, right = True, include_lowest = True)
```

2) Subsetting the categories

```
sub_c = c[0::4]
```

And here is the trouble, I want to append the last category to `sub_c`, like:

`sub_c.append(c[-1])` but I'm getting the error: `'Categorical' object has no attribute append.`

So how would I add on this category to the end then?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the last category together with the other categories:

```
sub_c = c[list(range(0, c.size, 4)) + [-1]].remove_unused_categories()
#[(-0.001, 1.0], (3.0, 4.0], (7.0, 8.0], (8.0, 9.0]], ...
```

Another option is to prepare a list of categorical codes:

```
codes = np.concatenate([c[0::4].codes, c[[-1]].codes])
sub_c = c.from_codes(codes, c.categories).remove_unused_categories()
#[(-0.001, 1.0], (3.0, 4.0], (7.0, 8.0], (8.0, 9.0]], ....
```

Don't forget to call `.remove_unused_categories()` to remove the unused categories.

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because append is an attribute of list, and not Categorical object.

So, to fix this error, you need to convert your pandas.core.categorical.Categories
 to list type by doing

```
sub_c = sub_c.tolist()
```

Then

```
sub_c.append(c.tolist()[-1])
```

will put the last element into sub_c but now sub_c is a list.